# How to add minutes to a date time value in orientdb

Tags: date, orientdb, addition

I want to add 5 minutes to a date time value and update the field.

like below. checkintime is a date time type. How do I do it in orientdb?

update employee set checkintime=sysdate()+5 return after

Comment: the below worked

update employee set checkintime=eval( "sysdate() + 300000") return after

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
update employee set checkintime=sum(sysdate().asLong(),300000).asDate()
```

**UPDATE**

I use this code and it works for me

```
create class employee extends v
create vertex employee set checkintime=sum(sysdate().asLong(),300000).asDate(), checkoldtime=sysdate()
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not working. It just sets the current time. Is this a bug?